# When did Marvelous Melmo's title get translated into English? And how?

Tags: marvelous-melmo

[Marvelous Melmo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marvelous_Melmo) is a manga from >40 years ago, apparently never released / translated for the English market, and its nice alliterative title makes me a bit curious of when and how the English title came to be.

Is it a ~2000s era title? Given how the Wikipedia's page history indicates a stub existed with the title in 2006?

Comment: Looks like there's [an official English translation of this manga](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/18071921-marvelous-melmo), though I can't find where's it's published.

Answer (score 2):

Kodansha’s 2012 [release](https://kc.kodansha.co.jp/product?item=0000043986) of the manga had Marvelous Melmo on the cover. The earliest use of the English title I can definitively pin down right now is the [old version](https://web.archive.org/web/20020424111941/http://en.tezuka.co.jp/manga/sakuhin/m078/m078_01.html) of the official Tezuka site via an archive.org capture from 2002, however The Anime Encyclopedia uses the title and that first came out in 2001 (although I only have the second and third revisions so can’t guarantee that Marvelous Melmo was named in the original edition).